# How to hide elements in mobile devices? CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to hide this sidebar in mobile devices, I tried this coding,

```
.sidebar__area:last-child .widget:last-child, .sidebar__area.is_stuck .widget:last-child{
display:none;
}
```

Which completely hid it.But when I try this, it doesn't work,

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 100px) and (max-device-width: 950px{
sidebar__area:last-child .widget:last-child, .sidebar__area.is_stuck .widget:last-child{
    display:none;
    }
```

Comment: You have a missing closing bracket (well, *parentheses* to be accurate) before the brace `(max-device-width: 950px {` Always validate your CSS.

Comment: Thanks! Works! @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 950px){
sidebar__area:last-child .widget:last-child, .sidebar__area.is_stuck .widget:last-child{
    display:none;
    }
```

Comment: Please vote and approve my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Did. :) Had to wait for a few minutes. :)